# Spring 5 Functional Web Framework is not working with Eureka Client

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-webflux, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Spring 5 Functional Web Framework is not working when I enable Microservice environment { Config-Server, Service-Registry(Eureka), Gateway(Zuul) }

I've a Maven + Spring Boot(v. 2.0.0.M3) + Spring Cloud(v. Finchley.M2) + JDO (DataNucleus) + MySQL application with Annotation based Rest Controller as well as Web Functional based RouterFunction.

When I run my application **Without Eureka Client Dependency.** Everything  works fine, My Annotation based & Functional calls working smoothly..

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Time when I run my application **With Eureka Client Dependency.**, Only Annotation based rest calls are working fine and Functional based calls returning 404..

Is there any other things that are required to register Router Functions in Spring cloud Microservice Environment?

Comment: It is a work in progress

Comment: I will continue with Annotation based approach. Thanks

Comment: Note: both webflux annotation and functional variants don't work yet, since it's work in progress, as Spencer pointed out. Spring MVC is of course supported.

Comment: Is it still in progress please?