# Spring Webflux including spring-cloud-starter-eureka breaks endpoints

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a basic hello world Webflux app that I want to include in a Spring cloud stack.  Whenever I add spring-cloud-starter-eureka to the project it launches Tomcat with a bunch of extra stuff and breaks my Webflux endpoints.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.M2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The output shows that the endpoints are mapped, but they always give a 404.

If I take out the Eureka starter everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This question asked the same thing and responses stated that the Webflux endpoints were not support yet.

[Spring 5 Functional Web Framework is not working with Eureka Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196773/spring-5-functional-web-framework-is-not-working-with-eureka-client)

Answer (score 0):

I use org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-**netflix**-eureka-client:2.0.0.RELEASE instead of spring-cloud-starter-eureka. This combines fine with webflux.